# About Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, measure-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I would like to understand why
$$
\frac{1}{M}\sum_{k=1}^M \mu (X_t^k, U_t^k) \cdot h \to \mathbb{E}\left[\int_\mathcal{U} \mu(X_t^\pi, u)\pi_t(u) \ \text{d} u \cdot h\right],
$$
by the Large of Large Numbers as $M\to\infty$. Here $X^1,\ldots, X^M$ is a sample which has been obtained by  $X^\pi$, where $\pi$ indicates that each $X^k$ is generate according to
$$
\text{d} X_t^U = \mu(X_t^U, U_t) \text{d} t + \sigma(X_t^U, U_t)\text{d}W_t
$$
with the corresponding $U^k$ sampled directly under the distribution induced by $\pi$. Particulary, I don't understand why the integral appears. Any hint, please?

Comment: I'm finding your description of your set-up hard to parse.  However, if I understand correctly, anytime you have an i.i.d. sequence $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and a (say, bounded) continuous function $F$, you get $N^{-1} \sum_{k = 1}^{N} F(X_{k}) \to \mathbb{E}(F(X_{1}))$ by the law of large numbers.  It looks like the map $U \mapsto X^{U}_{t}$ is continuous for each fixed $t$.

Comment: I feared it was a bit obscure, yes. Sorry for that, I'm following (p. 7) this paper (http://www.columbia.edu/~xz2574/download/rl.pdf). Yeah, that's right, thanks for your answer. However, I wonder why the integral comes up, because it seems a bit ad hoc they're adding that up... Of course it may be just my ignorance. Thanks!

Comment: If $\pi$ is the law of $U$ and $U$ takes values in a space $\mathcal{U}$, then $\mathbb{E}(F(U)) = \int_{\mathcal{U}} F(u) \, \pi(du)$.

Comment: Exactly. Then why do they write $\mathbb{E} [\int_\mathcal{U} \cdots]$?

Comment: Ah, well, $W$ is also random.  Are $U$ and $W$ independent?  In that case, at least morally, $X = F(W,U)$ and the joint distribution of $(W,U)$ would give you $\mathbb{E} \int_{\mathcal{U}} \dots \pi(du)$ provided $\mathbb{P}$ is understood as the law of $W$.  If each sample $X^{i}$ has its own independent copy of $U$ and $W$, I believe it should still be a straight-up application of LLN.

Comment: Oh, true. I was looking only at the $U$!, now is clear, thank you very very much.